# Change overflow:hidden in table to visible on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML table:

```css
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.a {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: white;
}

.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.a:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}

.c {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class=a><span class=c>a very long text that overflows</span></th>
    <th class=b>some other text that is very long and should only be partly obscured</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to accomplish is that the text in field a ("a very long text that overflows") becomes visible on hover. The table structure should not change.
And indeed it becomes visible, but the text that should be behind it (from field b) partly obscures it. The added span and z-indexes have also no effect. (Tested in Firefox and Chrome)

What I would like is that the text in field a becomes visible and obscures as much of field b as necessary.

Also available in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdn15kh8/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `th` that contains overflowing text:

```css
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.a {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.a:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}

.c {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class=a><span class=c>a very long text that overflows</span></th>
    <th class=b>some other text that is very long and should only be partly obscured</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Check [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) to understand stacking context.

Answer (score 2):

For `z-index` to work, it need a `position` aswell.

```
.a:hover {
   overflow: visible;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

[Fiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/tdn15kh8/26/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to the `.a`. The z-index need position:relative or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

There is also data attribute solution, that let you pass text from data attribute to ::after pseudo-class. It looks like this:

```css
table{width: 300px;}
table th{border: 1px solid black;z-index: 1;}
.a{max-width: 100px;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;background: white;}
.b{white-space: nowrap;}
.c{position: relative;}
.a:hover{overflow: visible;}
.a:hover .c::after{content:attr(data-text); display: block;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: green;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="a">
    <span class="c" data-text="a very long text that overflows">a very long text that overflows</span>
  </th>
  <th class="b">some other text</th>
</tr>
</table>
```